# simpliyfy C++ if else for multiple condition for range of values

Tags: c++, if-statement, std

I have multiple C++ if else conditions for checking range of certain variable and call function with same signature like

```
    if (x < 100 )
{
 call_1();
}
else if (x < 500 )
{
call_2();
}
else 
{
call_3();
}
```

Is any standard library or structure available so that I can map range and function which can be extended w/o touching conditional statements.?

Answer (score 8):

You could use `std::map` to store pointers to functions. Then you could use `std::map::lower_bound()` to find a correct function.

Here is a small example:

```
#include <map>
#include <limits>

void call_1() {}
void call_2() {}
void call_3() {}

std::map<int, void(*)()> functions = {
    { 99, &call_1 },
    { 499, &call_2 },
    { std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), &call_3 }
};

void call(int x)
{
    functions.lower_bound(x)->second();
}
```

Comment: You don't even have to dereference the function pointer: `functions.lower_bound(x)->second();`

Comment: @Rakete1111, yes, you are right. I have updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are no such "off the shelf" alternative that can help you here. The way you have it is nice and clear, but you can always be on the lookout for alternatives if clarity is maintained. For example, if `x` is, or could be, an unsigned integral type, and your intervals multiples of 100, then

```
switch (x / 100){
case 0:
    call_1();
    break;
case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
    call_2();
    break;
default:
    call_3();
}
```

might end up being more readable as your project scales.